# Can a custom search with refiners be done on sub-sites - SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

When I peruse this [link](https://www.credera.com/blog/technology-insights/microsoft-solutions/search-enjoy-sharepoint-2013-custom-search-faceting/) it indicates I must create this customized search via a web part and the standard search results page..  Thus, does this indicate I am confined to create this customization within my parent standard search results page and all of my sub sites will reflect this same search page ?

What if I wanted to have a different search page for my sub-sites ?  Are you only allowed one standard search results page (refiners on left hand side) per site collection.

Answer (score 1):

usually we create 1 separate site using "enterprise" or "basic" search centre template, then we configure all sub sites to use that search centre site, if you want to create separate search page for every sub site, you have to add refiner web part on every search page.

Comment: What type of configuration do you do

Comment: we create a sub site.